# How to create a "Setter" in Java

Tags: java, setter

I am unsure how to create a setter method in java.
Everything that I found on the internet either shows how to "generate" one in eclipse or doesn't include what I am looking for.

I am looking for a simple answer in plain terms, if that is possible.
I understand what a `setter-method` does, but am unsure about the syntax and specific code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also, if you generate it with Eclipse, just follow the same syntax to write it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are thinking of getters and setters from a C# perspective where there is actual built in syntax for them. Java doesn't have that. In Java a getter and setter is simply a function with the signature `Object getObject()` and `void setObject(Object object)`. Otherwise they aren't any different from other functions in java,besides  using the get/set naming convention. The reasoning behind the naming convention is to allow applications to easily find the accessor functions by means of reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A setter is a method which sets a value for one of your parameters. E.g. many people say it's not nice to have a public variable in a class:

```
public class SomeClass {
     public int someInt = 0;
}
```

now you can access the variable `someInt` directly:

```
SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
foo.someInt = 13;
```

You should rather do something like that:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someInt = 0;

    // Getter
    public int getSomeInt() {
        return someInt;
    }

    // Setter
    public void setSomeInt(int someIntNew) {
        someInt = someIntNew;
    }
}
```

and access it through:

```
SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
foo.setSomeInt(13);
```

All this is just convention... You could name your setter-method however you want! But getters and setters are a good (and readable) way to define access to your class varaibles as you like it (if you want to make it read-only you could just write the getter, if you don't wan't anybody to read the value you could only write the setter, you could make them protected, etc...)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It is simple and clear. I apologize for the late response but I decided to take a little break and work on another program in the hope to get a fresh look on this one when I returned.

Comment: you're welcome mate! I'm glad i could help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean a setter method as in set an object?

```
private String yourString;

public void setYourString(String yourString) {
    this.yourString = yourString;
}
```

This is basic code though so you probably mean something else?

Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

A small code for getter and setter

```
public class Test {

    String s;

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

}
```

Advantage of setter is that a setter can do sanity checks and throw `IllegalArgumentException`.