# Why i cant have a public class in a non public class?

Tags: java

How can i fix this code that it will work ?

```
  class Sample {
    public int a;
    private int b;
    int c;
    }
    public class ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample aClass = new Sample();
        aClass.a = 10;
        aClass.b = 10;
        aClass.c = 10;
    }
}
```

The error i got:

> The public type ex must be defined in its own file
>   The field Sample.b is not visible

Comment: can you provide the error message you got

Comment: `private int b;` - create a setter `setB(int b) {this.b = b;}` - or make in `public` see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: You cant access private variable from another class. You can access the public variable from a different class. Also, you can access the variable with the default modifier (i.e int c) from a different class if the class is in the same package. Have a look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a **Private** varaible form  **outside of the class**. What you have to do is change `private int b;` to `public int b;` or create a public setter method as in one of the comments pointed out.
For further clarification please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806159/how-to-create-a-setter-in-java)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`private` members cannot be accessed outside of class directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample {
    public int a;
    private int b;
    int c;
    public void setB(int b){
     this.b=b;
    }
   }
    public class ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample aClass = new Sample();
        aClass.a = 10;
        aClass.setB(10);//private variable not accessible directly
        aClass.c = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Variable scope** matters here. You can't access **private** variables out of the scope.

You have two options for this

1. Make your variables **public**

   ```
   class Sample {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    int c;
   }

   public class ex {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample aClass = new Sample();
        aClass.a = 10;
        aClass.b = 10;
        aClass.c = 10;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Keep your variables private and have **getters and setters**

   ```
   class Sample {
    public int a;
    private int b;
    int c;

    public int getB(){
      return this.b;
    }
    public void setB(int val){
      this.b = val;
    }
   }

   public class ex {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample aClass = new Sample();
        aClass.a = 10;
        aClass.setB(10);
        aClass.c = 10;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow best OOP practices for members. Always create a private members and make a public getters and setters.

```
public class Sample {

  private int a;
  private int b;
  private int c;

  public int getA() {
    return a;
  }

  public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public int getB() {
    return b;
  }

  public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public int getC() {
    return c;
  }

  public void setC(int c) {
    this.c = c;
  }
}
public class ex {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample aClass = new Sample();
    aClass.setA(10);
    aClass.setB(10);
    aClass.setC(10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following concept will solve your problem

1. public variable like `a` (you declared as `public int a;`) can be accessed using an object like `obj.a` (`aClass.a = 10;`)
2. Private variable like b (you declared as `private int b;`) cannot be accessed directly using an object like `obj.b`. Private variable can be accessed only within the class i.e you need to write a setter to do that. Following is the complete code you can try to implement

   class Sample {
        public int a;
         private int b;
        int c;

   ```
    public void setb(int b){
    this.b=b;
    }
    }
     public class ex {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       Sample aClass = new Sample();
       aClass.a = 10;
       aClass.setb(10);
       aClass.c = 10;
       }
       }
   ```